# Turn package.json into a series of npm install statements with patch

Tags: node.js, npm

Similar to a `patch` in git, is there a way to take a package.json that looks like this:

`"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
  }
}`

and output this:

`npm install --save-dev babel-core@6.18.2 babel-loader@6.2.8`

Comment: FWIW,  I don't think those are the same, are they?   The package.json will install updates past the ones you specified.  The command will install the specific version you specified.